# Django post data from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-views

I'm trying to send a string to a post view via checkbox being checked and unchecked. The part I am having trouble with is on the post view being able to get read the data.

I have the name being generated during the templating of the HTML to tell me the `id` of the item. Then the javascript is supposed to pass the name of the checkbox to the post view and then just `print` out the post value.

**Error**

The error I'm getting is that it returned a "`None`" so I'm thinking I'm not getting the name right.

In the `data` field of the javascript, I also tried "`data:{data:$header}`" and I got the same result.

**Javascript**

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {

      // console.log($header = $(this)[0].name)
      $header = $(this)[0].name

      $.post({
            url: "",
            data: $header,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
            }
        })

          });
```

**Django view.py**

```
class CurrentCodeView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    template_name = 'codes/currentCodes.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     //doing alot of stuff

    def post(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
        print(request.POST.get('data'))
```

Comment: Suggest that you search StackOverflow for the phrase 'django csrfmiddlewaretoken ajax' (without the quotes) and you should find your answer among the many results.  You need to send the data in the form:  data = {csrfmiddlewaretoken: value of token }

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I did look that up, but It doesn't appear to have a problem with CSRF token. Before I added in the `header` It was giving me an error that specified the CSRF token, now its just returning a value of `None` which Is why I was thinking I was not calling something correctly in my `post` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  You're not assigning a return value, and `print` doesn't return anything to the client.  This will return a response to the client:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    some_text = 'A reply'
    return JsonResponse({'some_text': some_text})
```

Comment: Thank you! I learned something new. So in order for the post request to be valid, it has to return something back? I can't just `print` the data sent.

Comment: Correct, and then you write Javascript code on the client side in order to access/use what you passed back.  Look at the examples here:  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/.