# Sending a POST request through Javascript on Django - failed to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to send a POST request to my Django view using plain javascript (I don't want any unnecessary libraries involved). The data is not sent through a form, but by using `fetch`. For now I just want to be able to manipulate the `request.POST`in my views.py, nothing more.

Here's my code:
**Javascript**

```
let article = document.querySelector('article')
articleId = article.getAttribute('data-product-id')

# some other stuff
fetch("{% url 'shop:shoplist' 1 %}", { 
              method: 'POST',
              dataType: "application/json", 
              data: {'article_id': articleId},
              headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token}
              })
```

**Python**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    testing = request.POST
    return JsonResponse({'test': testing})
```

The request is sent, the `csrftoken` is received correctly, but the `request.POST` returns just `<QueryDict: {}>`, instead of what I'm expecting (headers, data...).

I've searched and found a lot of similar questions, the most similar one being [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485191/django-post-data-from-javascript-function), but still I can't seem to find a solution.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request.POST` contains *only the parameters* that are *form encoded*. Since your data type is `application/json` they are empty. The `request.body` contains the actual json data.

Comment: I've tried to change the code with:  
`testing = request.body  
print(testing)`  
  
but the printed value is now `b''`

Comment: @Nobsyde: add `"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"` to the headers. I'm not sure what `dataType` does in your request.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add 'content-type' to headers in `fetch` call (instead of dataType parameter) and change data parameter to body with stringified object:

```
fetch("{% url 'shop:shoplist' 1 %}", { 
              method: 'POST',
              body: JSON.stringify({'article_id': articleId}),
              headers: {
                  'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token,
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }})
```

Comment: @Nobsyde try with `JSON.stringify`

Comment: oh wow sorry I didn't see you also changed the data (now body) parameter, it works!  To be more precise, both you and @blue_note have it right: there were 2 errors: (1) using `data` instead of `body` and (2) asking for `request.POST`instead of `request.body`. Thank you both!